# UAC when creating a windows share in Win10

Tags: c++, windows-10, uac, smb

in a VS C++ program we have to create and delete a windows share (dynamically). We use the `NetShareAdd(...)` and `NetShareDel(...)` functions to do so.

Since we switched to Win10, I need to run this program in elevated admin level ("run as Administrator") or change the UAC Execution Level in Project/Properties/Linker/Manifest File. Else the functions return with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (no matter, if the shared directory is in the users home or elsewhere on the disk).

The same thing I experienced, when I try to share the directory on commandline with `net share ...`. Cmd has to be started "as Administrator". Else I get "access denied". Maybe the security rules have changed from Win7 to Win10. As far as well.

My question is: how does the Windows Explorer share directories. When I share the same directory with the Explorer (RightClick on Directory/Properties/Share/Extended Share) I can do this as the "normal" user, without elevation, no question from UAC, no "run as Administrator" needed. Which functions does the explorer use. Or is this some "microsoft magic"?

Thank you.

Comment: The settings for UAC are flawered have a read of https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160816-00/?p=94105 Explorer (and other MS apps) are "trusted".

Comment: So, when I understand this article right: When I call these two functions in a thread, that  has thread injection rights into Explorer (I have still have to find out, what it is and how to do that), I don't need to run my whole program in elevated level (as long as the user has admin rights, which he does).

Comment: Conversely - any malware can do the same so any "sane" Windows 10 user has the slider in the 1st position - "Always notify me" - because DLL injection is relatively easy.  If you click [Start]  type "uac" click on "Change User Account Settings" and move the slider to the top position ("Always notify me") you should experience Explorer doing a UAC prompt as expected. What that article is arguing that position 1 is safe; positions 2, 3, 4 (never ask) are all the same as the bypass of 2 and 3 is simple.

Comment: So the answer to my question is: Because Explorer is a "trusted program", which can do silent elevation (or I could call it "microsoft magic")